# android multiple fragment in one tablet activity ,then Hide and Show Based on Button Click from other Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

1.In My Tablet Iam having One Activity, inside that Activity
I am Having 4 Fragments

Fragment1,Fragment2,Fragment3,Fragment4.

**My Need:**

**EDIT 1:**

2.Fragement1 ,Fragement4 Always Will Show **(Frag1||Frag4)-Initial Stage**, 
If Iam Clicking on a Button from **Fragement1-->>** Will Open the **Fragment2**(So it will show Like this **(Frag1||Frag2||Frag4)** in the Activity Screen).

3.if Iam Clicking on a Button from **Fragement2-->>**  Will Open the **Fragment3,** then **Fragemnt4** will be Hidden(So it will show Like this (**Frag1||Frag2||Frag3**) in the Activity Screen).

4.if we are clicking on the close icon From **Fragment3--->**,it will Show **(Fragment1||Fragment2||Fragment4)** Should Show.Hidden **frag4** is Replaced By **frag3**.

5.Finally, if i clicking on the close icon From **Fragment2--->**,**Frag2** will be Removed, it Will show Activity like Beginning **(Frag1||Frag4)**

Please Help me,How to achieve this.

[Link i referred](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/list_Fragment1xml_mainAct_ID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            class="com.knowledgeflex.lpm_qrt.Menu_Fragment1" >
        </fragment>

         <fragment
             android:id="@+id/detail_Fragmentxml_mainAct_ID"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight=".28"
             class="com.knowledgeflex.lpm_qrt.Option_Fragment3">
         </fragment>


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_Fragmentxml_mainAct_ID"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".92"
            class="com.knowledgeflex.lpm_qrt.Map_Fragment4">
        </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment1.class

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener 
{
    //Button android_btn, ios_btn, windows_btn;

    ImageView ALertIamge;



    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment1, container, false);


        // Initialize View
        ALertIamge=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.AlertImagexml);
       // ALertIamge.setOnClickListener(this);
        ALertIamge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Here I want Hide Show to Second Fragment
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

fragment2.class

```
 public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
    {



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.link_fragment2, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

fragment3.class

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment
{



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options_fragment3, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Fragment4.class

```
public class Fragment4 extends Fragment
    {



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.options_fragment4, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the source code you got and what you tried

Comment: @AlexandreMartin Please check my Question .

Comment: I did, but I think Lino already answered your question correctly so you should give him credits for his work and take a deeper look at his solution.

Comment: My problem was first Hide and Show,not Commuticating With other Fragmanet

Comment: then use add, remove and replace transactions like Lino shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so on close button click you have to do this

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(this).commit();

this means your current fragment if your button is in fragment 3 and you want to hide fragment 3 
if you want to completely remove it then use remove instead of hide
and if you want to replace fragment 3 with 4 that or 4 with 3 that is easy

replacing any fragment  with fragment 3        `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cntainer,fragment3,"fragment3").commit();`

replacing fragment 3 with 4

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cntainer,fragment4,"fragment4").commit();

**update**
as your fragments are static you can do this

```
Fragment fragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_Fragmentxml_mainAct_ID);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment).commit();
```

put this in you on click

Comment: in Fragment1  one ICon is Available ,Clicking on that Icon Fragment3 will open along with Fragment 4. if iam closing(Close  ICon Inside Fragment3) the Frament3, Only Fragment1 and fragmant 4 Should Show. Fragmant3 Will be Hidden

Comment: that would be the case if you take one frame layout id as container and want to add fragment to it dynamically so then you can use replacing fragments because framelayout can show you one fragment at one time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115636/discussion-between-kumar-and-arif-nouman-khan).

Answer (score 2):

if the button is inside the main activity, then you display the fragment directly using

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(yourFragment, "yourTAG").commit();
```

conversely, if the button is inside fragment 1 or 4 then you have to communicate back to the activity:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Same thing if your close button is inside the fragment 3.

Comment: Please can you add any sample?

Comment: @Lino Please Check My Updated Question.